# Oracle 12c sample schema "hr_main.sql" script is not working

Tags: database, oracle, schema, oracle12c

I've been working with Oracle for the past few days and I'm trying to set up local Oracle 12c Std. on my machine. And I've been driving myself crazy trying to get the sample schemas set up for testing and education.

First my install didn't have the scripts, so I fetched them off GitHub and pasted them in the schema directory.

https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/tag/v12.2.0.1

Then I executed the command in SQLPLUS from my OCA book

> SQL>@?\demo\schema\human_resources\hr_main.sql

and this is my output:

```
    specify connect string as parameter 6:
    Enter value for 6: localhost:1521\neworcl

    SP2-0556: Invalid file name.
    DROP USER hr CASCADE
      *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist


    CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED BY *****
        *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name


    ALTER USER hr DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
       *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist


    ALTER USER hr TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
       *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist


    GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE VIEW, ALTER SESSION, CREATE SEQUENCE TO hr
                                                                 *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist


    GRANT CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE DATABASE LINK, RESOURCE , UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO hr
                                                                           *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist


    ERROR:
    ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist


    Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
    SP2-0640: Not connected
    ERROR:
    ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist


    SP2-0640: Not connected
    SP2-0640: Not connected
    ******  Creating REGIONS table ....
    SP2-0640: Not connected
    SP2-0640: Not connected
    SP2-0640: Not connected
```

(output continues with 'Not Connected' for a long time)

I read something in my research that short, common user names have to be notated with 'C##' before it will be accepted as a user/schema name. I tried messing around with that and couldn't make it happy.

I think it also doesn't like my connector string.

Does anyone have any insight? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Do you remember - when you installed Oracle 12, did you install it as a multitenant database (with the Container database / Pluggable database arrangement), as a single standalone database? If it's the former, did you try to create the HR schema in the ROOT (which is essentially illegal), or did you connect to a "user-defined" PDB (normally exactly one is created upon installation)?

Comment: Hi: I can only have one database because I am using the standard free version. When I installed the database, I am fairly confident that I accepted all the defaults (easy local machine install), and just set the admin password and gave it a name.

Comment: I've installed it more than once thinking perhaps the install was bad, because it didn't seem to have all the schema files it was supposed to. The HR schema directory only has one .sql file. Not sure what that's about.

But I'm just trying to get this set up man, I got the OCA SQL Fundamentals study guide and hoping I can grind through it.

Comment: After doing some more research I found that it's needed to connect to the PDB and not the CDB. Really I don't totally understand the difference; I am new to databases. But I believe that I am now in the PDB and ran the scripts again, and the output still complains but isn't nearly as scary.

I believe now my issue is with the "specify connect string as parameter 6"
Can anyone confirm what this needs to be? I inputted localhost:1521/neworcl